# Using try-except statement with signal.pause() function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using `Raspberry Pi` and library `gpiozero`. I initialize a button connected to the board and want to process the event when the button is held. For this I try to use an exception. Below is the code:

```
from signal import pause
from gpiozero import Button

class pressException( Exception ):
    pass

def raisePressException():
    raise pressException( 'Button held' )

push = Button( 5 )
push.when_held = raisePressException

try:
    pause()
except pressException:
    print( 'Exception accepted' )
```

However, once I hold the button, the exception block doesn't catch this exception, since it's emitted somehow not from inside of pause(). The terminal output as follows:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 460, in held
    parent._fire_held()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 364, in _fire_held
    self.when_held()
  File "test.py", line 8, in raisePressException
    raise pressException( 'Button held' )
pressException: Button held
```

How can I catch this exception? Or is there another way to process such an event in the same scope where `Button` was initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this,

```
from signal import pause
from gpiozero import Button

class pressException( Exception ):
    pass

def raisePressException():
    raise pressException( 'Button held' )

try:
    push = Button( 5 )
    push.when_held = raisePressException()
    pause()
except pressException:
    print( 'Exception accepted' )
```

The reason this happens is you are raising the error outside the try and except and hence it cannot catch the error, and also you were calling your own raise function in a loop, even if you try and catch your own code, it will end up in a recursion loop

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error. I corrected the code, it had wrong indents before. The line `push.when_held = raisePressException()` executes the function and assigns returned value (what is nothing in this case) to push.when_held() function. It's not actually what I want. The idea is that the function is not executed immediately but once the button is held. Here (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/gpiozero/stable/gpiozero.pdf) on p.7 how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

that raise from this line

```
raise pressException( 'Button held' )
```

so you must wrap with `try ... except` the right line,
that one, or the level up, where you run raisePressException

btw, this make no sense:

```
def raisePressException():
    raise pressException( 'Button held' )
    push = Button( 5 )        # not able to be reached or achieved.
    push.when_held = raisePressException
```

just use

```
    raise pressException( 'Button held' )
```

Comment: Sorry, initially I copied the code with wrong indents. Now it's fixed. Using your suggestion, I indeed can catch it inside the `raisePressException()` function. Is there a way to catch exception in the global scope?